# Keystore file Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'

Tags: android, keystore

I updated android studio and my keystore path must had changed in the process. I have tried the "Choose Existing " button but cannot find what I am looking for.  I do not know where to find it. Would anyone please give me some instruction where to look?

I looked everywhere, I read a other posts with similar problems but debugging and it didn't help because I am attempting a new release.  I have also searched for a software program to help me retrieve the path but I have been unsuccessful with that as well.

Below is the error message I get when I attempt to generate a signed apk.  I did save the apk's from older versions that I had generated, if that helps at all.

The error is as follows after android studio attempts compiling:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease] 
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file C:\Users\aform\OneDrive\Documents\xxxxxxx\xxxx  not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

I am also working on a new PC, but I got the same error of my previous PC as well.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 35):

Check your `keystore` path and also **example.jks** file location all are correct. find the location where the `keystore` path was generated for the first time. check at **C:\Users<user>.android**

Comment: "find the location where the keystore path was generated for first time" , where would I look for that location?  In which file would I find the KeyStore?

Comment: most probably it would be at **C:\Users\.Username**

Comment: Thanks, now I have a password issue.  Your solution helped, Thank you very much

Comment: There is no "accept answer" option,  Your answer lead to the correct place to solve my problem.

Comment: can u see a tick mark below voting button click on that??

Comment: I have looked, and there is no button to click.  I want to help, I am grateful for your help.  There is nothing to accept your answer.

Comment: then leave it :)

Comment: it often occurs when you git clone from your own repo. Because key.properties file is not being checked out.

Answer (score 12):

If you're using React Native, Just copy the

```
C:\Users\UserName\.android\debug.keystore
```

and paste it in the path

```
ProjectPath\android\app\
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 7):

You have misplace the path to the key store.jks file. Search for the file on your computer and use the path and everything will work Great!!

Comment: What if the file is nowhere to be found, is there a way to recreate it?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem!
you need to invalidate the studio cache and restart in. it works for this kind of issues.
**Steps**

1. Go to file at the top left corner.
2. On file, click invalidate Caches / Restart
3. A pop up box appears. Click Invalidate and Restart.
   [![enter image description here][1]][1]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4jSb.jpg

   After this go ahead to generate you Signed App for playstore

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue in Windows. It worked when I changed the slash type in *key.properties*

Use

```
storeFile=C:/Users/...
```

instead of

```
storeFile=C:\Users\...
```

Comment: This is the CORRECT answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
cd android
cd app

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-debug-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000


keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

**Using this your keystore file Error app:validateSigningRelease'  is Solved**

Comment: Although this may be a correct answer. Code only answers aren't useful without an explanation of what and how it solves the original question. Please provide details to your answer.

Comment: usign this you can generate debug keystrore throgh command line

Comment: Please edit your answer and add more details. People may not see your comments. You could also comment the lines of your code with what each line does and what the expected output will be.

Comment: using this i have increase expiry time

Answer (score 3):

I saved my key.jks file in my Projects android->app folder

And in key.properties I changed the path to storeFile=key.jks

this makes your file locate inside the app so path is very clear for compiler

I do this for every project

Answer (score 2):

I saved my key.jks file in my Projects
[android->app folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loPw1.png)

And in key.properties I changed the path to [storeFile=key.jks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bciw.png)

Answer (score 2):

**

### This Happens when flutter SDK can't find the signing key.

**

**To Resolve This:**

Step 1: Check `android/key.properties` file.
if `key.properties` do not exist create one.

Step 2: Add Proper values in key.properties

```
  storePassword=
  keyPassword=
  keyAlias=
  storeFile=
```

Step 3: Add These lines in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android{
 ...
 ...
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
 }

 buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

For React-native the

`gradlew assembleRelease`

command generate release APK so make sure to include release key-store (not the debug one) in

**`{project}/android/app`**

generate release key-store

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 2):

i faced this issue when tried to update/publish next version of my app to Samsung Store / Galaxy Store. and the solution is

1. your package name must be same as per the previous version
2. you must have .jks file
3. Copy your .jks file and paste it to Android Studio->app folder.
4. Android Studio -> select project from drop down -> you'll see the .jks file in project structure. copy the relative path of the file.
5. now build.gradle(app) -> inside **signingConfigs** -> update your file path like this

> storeFile file('/Volumes/Device/Projct/myproject/my jks file')

6. the keyalias must be same as per previous app. (you can check the keyalias from .jks file)
7. Android Studio -> bottom left corner there is a tab **Build Variants** click on it and select **Release**
8. now make .apk file.
9. samsung store will not accept Signed apk.

you're done!

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate key:

```sh
cd ./android/app
sudo keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have given a path of JKS file in

```
  signingConfigs {
         config {
             storeFile file('/home/Android/xxxxxxxxxx/JKS/xxxxxxxxxxx.jks')
             storePassword '***************'
             keyAlias = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
             keyPassword '***************'
         }
     }
```

then please locate your JKS file path in this so, you resolve the error. In my case, this solution is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had to copy paste the file "my-upload-key.keystore" into my project's android->app folder and this solved the problem for me.

Incase you dont have the "my-upload-key.keystore" file, you can create it by using the following 3 steps (for windows):
1) open you command prompt as administrator
2) make sure you re not in any folder and you see C:> as address
3) run command `keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` and you will see the file in your C directory

For Linux you can run the same command in terminal, even in your project and move the file to andorid->app

Comment: after pasting in app folder what path did you give to the storeFile = ??

Answer (score 0):

**Actully This happen because you have remove your keystorefile from your project path.**

If you have upload your app on play store then you should use that app old keystone file if you don't use that file it will get reject from play store

If you don't have created keystone file then use this

```
sudo keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

past that json file in

```
Projectname/android/app/my-upload-key.keystore
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your keystore path!

For me it was the way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33277011)

Answer (score 0):

- **SO: Windows 11**
- **Programming language:** React Native
- **React Native Version:** 0.72
- **Official documentation:** https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#migrating-old-android-react-native-apps-to-use-app-signing-by-google-play

In my case, I had generated the `my-upload-key-key.keystore` file from the CMD in Windows due to permissions issues with the visual studio code terminal.

I generated this in the path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.18.10-hotspot\bin`

From that path I had copied the `my-upload-key.keystore` file and pasted it into the `Myproject/android/ path`, but the `my-upload-key.keystore` file should be in the `Myproject/android/app` path. Moving the `my-upload-key.keystore` to the correct path fixed the error.